Vulkan vkCmdCopyBuffer with Semaphores
I am trying to copy data from one buffer to another.
I have two VkSemaphores (each buffer has one) that should be checked before the copying process starts. And which should be signaled when the copy process is complete.
My VkSubmitInfo is filled in the following way:
VkSemaphore semaphores[2] = {dstBuffer.semaphore, srcBuffer.semaphore};

VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 2;
submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = semaphores;

submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 2;
submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = semaphores;
submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = ??? 

submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer;

vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

What value do I have to enter in the variable pWaitDstStageMask? The input is an array of VkPipelineStageFlags elements. But I am not using the pipeline here. I tried the following:
submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

But my validation layer said:
VUID_Undefined(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 2044605652 - Validation Error: [ VUID_Undefined ] Object 0: handle = 0x22d0dab43e0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x79de34d4 | vkQueueSubmit: required parameter pSubmits[0].pWaitDstStageMask specified as NULL.
Objects: 1
    [0] 0x22d0dab43e0, type: 3, name: NULL

Therefore something else must be inserted there

Buffer copy synchronization is typically handled via memory barriers. Once the memory barrier is satisfied the data is in place and ready to work with.
